# Can I open Sales Path in web using deep-linking?

Tags: salesforce1-app

[Sales Path](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000212203&language=en_US) allows the dynamic display of up to five fields plus guidance text customised by opportunity record type and stage, but is available in Salesforce1 only at this time.

If I open an opportunity in mobile-emulation mode in a browser, the URL is something like

> https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/one/one.app#/sObject/{OpportunityId}/view?t=1436966667080

How could I open this URL in a Visualforce page? I would then expose this VF page as a tab in a custom console component in the Salesforce Console in order to present the Sales Path view of the opportunity on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using the link in my dev org and got this to come up in Chrome. I did it using Chrome's Developer Tools set for Mobile Emulation. Here's a screen shot of what it would look like.

[image: SalesPathDeepLinkingEmulation]

It came up as a Lightning Page which as you can see, didn't look anything like what's on the link you referred us to. Regardless, this isn't going to show up as a regular desktop app. You'd need open it in its own tab and it won't have the full functionality of the SF1 app. It will slide between the 3 screen, at least it does for me. I just don't see the Decision Maker Guidance functionality which I think is what you're looking for.

Comment: I should have included a screenshot - the Decision Maker Guidance dies display nicely. I think the parameter in the URL must refer to the Sales Path defined and activated for a given record type, so you would need to define a sales Path in your organisation, then open an opportunity in /one/one.app to get the URL parameter for your sales path.